# While loop foreach returning values that are repeated in next for loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, while-loop

What is happening in my code is I'm passing a keyword through a query. For each keyword I want to run the array get the results for that keyword and insert them into my database.

The issue I'm running into is that instead of getting keyword inspiration and passing that through once it carries the value from that query, into the next.

So for instance I have. values `returning id = 8, 9, 10, 11, 12`. Then the next query for insert should only return 5 more but instead for the next keyword it carries these values through. so it might be `8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17`.

If I up that value to `3`. It would carry this `8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17` through and add five more entries to that. I'm not sure in my code where this is happening.

Maybe a simpler example. I query a list of 2 keywords. Then out of those keywords I need to query 1 keyword through `sql2` then out of all those values place them into `sql3`. What's happening is that instead of dropping the first keyword, it carries the results through the second time. So if I query the keyword inspiration and inspire. It will query inspiration once, the second tiem around it will query inspiration and inspire. Instead of just querying inspire the second time around.

```
$sql = "
SELECT `id` , `title`
FROM `mf8uz_categories`
WHERE `extension` = 'com_hwdmediashare'
LIMIT 0 , 2";
$getInfo = mysql_query($sql);
//$numResults = mysql_num_rows($getInfo);
  while($keywordArray = mysql_fetch_array($getInfo))
    $keywords[] = $keywordArray;
    foreach($keywords as $keyword){ 
    $keyWord = $keyword['title'];
    $categoryId = $keyword['id'];
//  echo $categoryId . $keyWord . "</br>" . "</br>";
    $sql2 = "SELECT `id`, `title`,`description`
FROM `mf8uz_hwdms_media`
WHERE `title` LIKE '%$keyWord%'
OR `description` LIKE '%$keyWord%'
LIMIT 0 , 5";
//echo $sql2 . "<br>";
echo $keyWord . "-------";
$getResults = mysql_query($sql2);
//echo $getResults;
echo mysql_errno($db_server) . ": " . mysql_error($db_server) . "\n";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getResults))
    $rows[] = $row;
    //echo $row . "</br>" . "HERE" ;
    foreach($rows as $row)  {
    $echoDescription = $row['description'];
    $echoRow = $row['title'];
    $videoId = $row['id'];
    echo $videoId . "</br>" . $echoDescription . "</br>" . $echoRow . "</br>";
//  echo "category ID equals" . $categoryId . " " . "video id is:" . $videoId ." ". "title is:" . $echoRow . " " . "Keyword Is:" . $keyWord . "</br>";

$sql3 = "INSERT INTO `btheman_dwjo21c4`.`mf8uz_hwdms_category_map` (
`id` ,
`element_type` ,
`element_id` ,
`category_id` ,
`ordering` ,
`created_user_id` ,
`created`
)
VALUES (
'', '1', '$videoId', '$categoryId', '0', '666', '2013-11-27 16:39:09'
);";

//$getResults = mysql_query($sql3);
//echo $sql3 . "  " . $echoRow . "</br>";
echo mysql_errno($db_server) . ": " . mysql_error($db_server) . "\n";
}
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thank you. I'm just learning. Should I change all of them in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is you are simply not initing or reseting `$row` in each loop.  For example, this line stands out to me:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getResults))
    $rows[] = $row;
    //echo $row . "</br>" . "HERE" ;
    foreach($rows as $row)  {
```

You are always adding items to `$rows`.  So why not do this instead:

```
 $rows = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getResults))
    $rows[] = $row;
    //echo $row . "</br>" . "HERE" ;
    foreach($rows as $row)  {
```

I believe simply adding an `array()` init via `$rows = array();` will solve this issue. But still looking at the code to see if there is something else.

**EDIT** Okay found another similar issue here:

```
//$numResults = mysql_num_rows($getInfo);
  while($keywordArray = mysql_fetch_array($getInfo))
    $keywords[] = $keywordArray;
```

Notice the `$keywords[]` yet the array is never inited or reset? Do this:

```
$keywords = array();
//$numResults = mysql_num_rows($getInfo);
  while($keywordArray = mysql_fetch_array($getInfo))
    $keywords[] = $keywordArray;
```

Adding that `$keywords = array();` will ensure that each loop through `while($keywordArray = mysql_fetch_array($getInfo))` gets reset to provide you with the proper results.

**ANOTHER EDIT** I reformatted your code—and added my fixes in the process—so I could more clearly see what is happening. In general, whenever you properly cleanup & format you code, you make it easier to debug & spot choke-points. If you ever run into an issue you are banging your head against the wall with, just see if you can clean up the code a bit & before you know it, problems are solved!

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` , `title`"
     . " FROM `mf8uz_categories`"
     . " WHERE `extension` = 'com_hwdmediashare'"
     . " LIMIT 0,2"
     ;

$getInfo = mysql_query($sql);
// $numResults = mysql_num_rows($getInfo);

$keywords = array();
while($keywordArray = mysql_fetch_array($getInfo)) {
  $keywords[] = $keywordArray;
}

foreach ($keywords as $keyword) { 
  $keyWord = $keyword['title'];
  $categoryId = $keyword['id'];
  // echo $categoryId . $keyWord . "</br>" . "</br>";
  $sql2 = "SELECT `id`, `title`,`description`"
        . " FROM `mf8uz_hwdms_media`"
        . " WHERE `title` LIKE '%$keyWord%'"
        . " OR `description` LIKE '%$keyWord%'"
        . " LIMIT 0 , 5"
        ;
  // echo $sql2 . "<br>";
  echo $keyWord . "-------";
  $getResults = mysql_query($sql2);
  //echo $getResults;
  echo mysql_errno($db_server) . ": " . mysql_error($db_server) . "\n";

  $rows = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getResults)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
  }

  //echo $row . "</br>" . "HERE" ;
  foreach($rows as $row)  {
    $echoDescription = $row['description'];
    $echoRow = $row['title'];
    $videoId = $row['id'];
    echo $videoId . "</br>" . $echoDescription . "</br>" . $echoRow . "</br>";
    //  echo "category ID equals" . $categoryId . " " . "video id is:" . $videoId ." ". "title is:" . $echoRow . " " . "Keyword Is:" . $keyWord . "</br>";

    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO `btheman_dwjo21c4`.`mf8uz_hwdms_category_map` (
    `id` ,
    `element_type` ,
    `element_id` ,
    `category_id` ,
    `ordering` ,
    `created_user_id` ,
    `created`
    )
    VALUES (
    '', '1', '$videoId', '$categoryId', '0', '666', '2013-11-27 16:39:09'
    );";

    //$getResults = mysql_query($sql3);
    //echo $sql3 . "  " . $echoRow . "</br>";
    echo mysql_errno($db_server) . ": " . mysql_error($db_server) . "\n";
  } // end foreach '$rows'

} // end foreach '$keywords'
```

Comment: BINGO. Solved it. Thank you.